# Unable to upload image file to s3 from React with Node presigned url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image file to an AWS S3 bucket. I am using Node/Express to generate a presigned URL to upload said image directly to s3 from the React frontend. The thing is I am able to upload the file as a file (same size as on local PC) but it does not have the file extension. That is, it has only the signed character e.g. `9c9743b9-4dd7-4afa-af06-c060fb0fb175` with file type of file instead of `9c9743b9-4dd7-4afa-af06-c060fb0fb175.png` with png file type

Here is a brief snippet of what I have tried so far

Backend

```js
// My controller
try {
  const payload = await AwsS3Service.getSignedUrlService();
  res.status(200).send({ 
      success: true, 
      data: payload
  });
  ...
```

```js
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  region: config.awsS3.region,
  accessKeyId: config.awsS3.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.awsS3.secretAccessKey,
  signatureVersion: config.awsS3.signatureVersion
})

const getSignedUrlService = async () => {
  const imageName = crypto.randomUUID()

  const params = ({
    Bucket: config.awsS3.bucketName,
    Key: imageName,
    Expires: 120 // in sec
  })

  const uploadUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
  return uploadUrl
}
```

Frontend

```js
  const [final, setFinal] = useState<FileList | any>('')
  const [img, setImg] = useState<typeof formState.file>(null)

  const handleImageChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files && e.target.files[0]
    if (e.target.files) { 
      setFinal(e.target.files[0]!)
    }
    const { type, name } = file as File
    setImgName(name)
    setImgType(type)

    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      setImg(e.target?.result)
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file as Blob)
  }

  const handleFormSubmit: SubmitHandler<IImage> = async (data: IImage) => {
    
    try {
      const signedUrl = await axios({ method: 'GET', url: `${config.API_URL}/awss3` })
      
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', final[0])   

      const resUpload = await fetch(`${signedUrl.data.data}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        body: final
      })

      if (resUpload.status === 200) {
        // redirect
      }
    } catch(err: any) {
      alert(`An error occured. ${err.message}`)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <Stack>
        <Box>
            <InputLabel htmlFor='imgfile'>Image File</InputLabel>
            <picture>
              { img 
                ? <img src={img} alt='Image preview' height={90} width={160} /> 
                : <Box sx={{ height: 90, width: 160, backgroundColor: '#555' }}></Box>
              }
            </picture>
            <input type='file' accept='image/*' id='imgfile' name='imgFile' onChange={handleImageChange} />
        </Box>
      </Stack>
      <Button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
```

I have been unable to solve this for a while now. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: any response you are getting?

Comment: @Balaji Do you mean response from backend server? If so, it is 200

Comment: why presigned URL why not direct uploading file to S3 using SDK

Comment: I pretty much came across a similar situation and what I did was. once I generate the presigned url, I tried to upload the file from a postman request to know the first part is working as expected. If you are able to do the same, then you need some tweaks from the UI only. @dEBAM

Comment: @AvinashDalvi I saw this approach implemented with vanila JS and found it interesting. The sdk is used only in the backend. The frontend has to simply submit form and save URL only.

Comment: have you seen Javascript SDK https://github.com/AvinashDalvi89/aws-s3-file-upload-progress here is one of example.

Comment: @AvinashDalvi The advantage we get through presigned url upload is the bandwith is directly from client to AWS servers. If we do it with SDK, then our hosted environment comes into picture which might have some limitations on speed of upload. Performance wise its faster than the SDK uploads

Comment: if possible can create JsFiddle for your code ?

Comment: Maybe I will try in Stackblitz

Comment: @AvinashDalvi Stackblitz demo but without the backend and signed URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-n7q16w?file=UploadImage.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a self-answer just in case anyone is interested.

I managed to work around this by adding the file name, type, and extension when making the sign request as a POST request instead and attaching the file name and file type in the request body.

```js
// Frontend
const signedUrl = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${config.API_URL}/awss3`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: { name: imgName, type: imgType }
})
```

And added them in the `Key`

```js
// Backend
const getSignedUrlService = async (name, type) => {
  // name and type from req.body
  const imageName = crypto.randomUUID() + '-' + name

  const params = ({
    Bucket: config.awsS3.bucketName,
    Key: imageName,
    ContentType: type,
    Expires: 120 // in sec
  })

  const uploadUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
  return uploadUrl
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: Right Key is important part. Thanks for answer.